# Getting 444 response code while trying to web scrape in Python in Python using Request function and via scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to make a request to "https://www.walmart.com/search/?page=1&query=" using request function or using scrapy module but getting the response code 444.

See below my snippet:

```
headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
res = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/', headers=headers)
cookie = res.cookies
res1 = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/search/?page=1&query=',headers=res.headers,cookies=cookie)
```

But I m getting the `res1.status_code` as `444`. Would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should reuse request elements:

```python
import requests

with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers.update(
        {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                          "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                          "Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 "
                          "Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
        }
    )
    _ = connection.get("https://www.walmart.com/")
    response = connection.get('https://www.walmart.com/search/?page=1&query=')
    print(response.status_code)
```

Output (status code):

```
200
```

Comment: I have one more query related to python scrapy, please have a look